# How to clone an array of objects in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object, clone

I have an array of objects. I know that objects get assigned by "reference" and arrays by "value". But when I assign the array, each element of the array is referencing the object, so when I modify an object in either array the changes are reflected in the other.

Is there a simple way to clone an array, or must I loop through it to clone each object?

Comment: References to objects are assigned by value.</unnecessarypedantry>

Answer (score 63, accepted):

References to the same objects already get copied when you copy the array. But it sounds like you want to <strike>shallow-copy</strike> deep-copy the objects being referenced in the first array when you create the second array, so you get two arrays of distinct but similar objects.

The most intuitive way I can come up with right now is a loop; there may be simpler or more elegant solutions out there:

```
$new = array();

foreach ($old as $k => $v) {
    $new[$k] = clone $v;
}
```

Comment: What he's doing right now is _shallow copying_, he wants to _deep copy_. Your code is right, but your terminology isn't, though.

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen: Am I not shallow-copying the objects rather than just shallow-copying the array?

Comment: @BoltClock: Whether you are shallow-coyping the objects depends on the implementation of clone of the specific object; that's up to the designer of the object, not the user. For instance, if one of the objects in the array contains references to another object and a proper `__clone` function hasn't been implemented, it wil still only be a shallow copy. In other words: If the developer of the object you're cloning did it right, it'll be a deep copy.

Comment: @BoltClock no, you deep-copying array and elements of array. Your code in answer is correct, anyway.

Comment: Got it, I forgot PHP provides a `__clone()` method for implementing deep copy, and was assuming default shallow copy behavior with `clone`.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat just to know: `clone` not always can create independent copy, read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php):  *`Any properties that are references to other variables, will remain references.`*

Comment: I only need a shallow copy of each object (the objects only contain values) so this answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 65):

```
$array = array_merge(array(), $myArray);
```

Comment: That is very smart! Much cleaner than a foreach loop!

Comment: Is this actually different to $array = $myArray? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532618/is-there-a-function-make-a-copy-of-a-php-array-to-another

Comment: @GeorgeLund No, this is not any different. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php#92346

Comment: Queue Spongebob narrator, "Six hours later..." I have a different problem, and my journey has taken me back here. Who would have thunk? I needed a way to clone an array while preserving the references all while leaving the internal pointer untouched. This does exactly that. +1.

Comment: After a good night's rest, I came to a realization that I didn't need `array_merge()`. I've added an answer to a similar question with my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17729234/1134804

Comment: In this solution we lost original numeric keys from $myArray: "Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array."

Comment: This is not cloning the objects in the array (like it was asked)! So I don't understand this answer and the high voting? It is nearly the same like $arrB = $arrA, just that numeric keys are getting reindexed.

Comment: Smarter: $array = (array)$myArray;

Comment: Smartest: *reading the question carefully*, and realizing this answer does not do what the question asks - nor do the variations given in these comments!

Answer (score 28):

You need to clone objects to avoid having references to the same object.

```
function array_copy($arr) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) $newArray[$key] = array_copy($value);
        else if(is_object($value)) $newArray[$key] = clone $value;
        else $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: Simple, yet effective. I use it as a static function.

Comment: +1 I accidentally stole your function without realizing it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17729234/1134804. I've been to this page a number of times, but I always scroll down until I found some answers with high vote counts (thus skipping yours). It's almost the same exact function, and I've never even glanced at your answer until just now!

Answer (score 25):

As suggested by AndreKR, using array_map() is the best way to go if you already know that your array contains objects:

```
$clone = array_map(function ($object) { return clone $object; }, $array);
```

Answer (score 7):

I opted for clone as well. Cloning an array does not work (you could consider some arrayaccess implementation to do so for you), so as for the *array clone* with **array_map**:

```
class foo {
    public $store;
    public function __construct($store) {$this->store=$store;}
}

$f = new foo('moo');
$a = array($f);

$b = array_map(function($o) {return clone $o;}, $a);

$b[0]->store='bar';    
var_dump($a, $b);
```

#### Array clone with serialize and unserialize

If your objects support serialisation, you can even sort of *deep shallow copy/clone* with a tour into their sleeping state and back:

```
$f = new foo('moo');
$a = array($f);

$b = unserialize(serialize($a));

$b[0]->store='bar';
var_dump($a, $b);
```

However, that can be a bit adventurous.

Answer (score 4):

A pure PHP 7.4 >= solution:

```
$cloned = array_map(fn ($o) => clone $o, $original);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop it (possibly using a function like `array_map()` for that), there is no PHP function to automatically perform a deep copy of an array.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it like this:

```
function array_clone($array) {
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$value) {
        if(is_object($value)) {
            $value = clone $value;
        }
    });
    return $array;
}
```

The function arg copies the array without cloning the objects,
then each nested object is cloned. So it won't work if the algorithm is not used inside a function.

Note this function clone the array recursively. You can use `array_walk` instead of `array_walk_recursive` if you do not want this to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my best practice on an array of objects and cloning. Usually it is a good idea, to have a Collection class for each class of objects (or interface), which are used in an array. With the magic function `__clone` cloning becomes a formalized routine:

```
class Collection extends ArrayObject
{
     public function __clone()
     {
        foreach ($this as $key => $property) {
            $this[$key] = clone $property;
        }
     }
}
```

To clone your array, use it as Collection and then clone it:

```
$arrayObject = new Collection($myArray);
$clonedArrayObject = clone $arrayObject;
```

One step further, you should add a clone method to your class and each sub-class, too. This is important for deep cloning, or you might have unintended side effects:

```
class MyClass
{
     public function __clone()
     {
        $this->propertyContainingObject = clone $this->propertyContainingObject;
     }
}
```

An important note on using ArrayObject is, that you cannot use `is_array()` any longer. So be aware of this on refactoring your code.

Answer (score 1):

or also

```
$nuarr = json_decode(json_encode($array));
```

but it is expensive, I prefer Sebastien version (array_map)

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by pointed by default and are not always easy to clone especially as they may have circular references. You would be better suited with a different choice of data structures.

For those providing solutions to shallow copy the easier way is this:

```
 $b = (array)$a;
```

For deep copies I do not recommend this solution:

> $nuarr = json_decode(json_encode($array));

This is for a deep copy. It only supports a subset of PHP types and will swap objects to array or arrays to objects which might not be what you want as well as potentially corrupting binary values and so on.

If you make a manual recursive function for deep copies the memory usage will be much less afterwards for scalar values and keys so using json or any serializer an impact beyond its point of execution.

It may be better to use unserialize(serialize($a)) for deep copies if performance is not a concern which has wider support for things such as objects though I would not be surprised if it breaks for circular references and several other unusual things.

array_merge_recursive or array_walk_recursive can also be used for arrays.

You can easily create your own recursive function that uses is_object and is_array to choose the appropriate means of copying.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 5 and above one can use `ArrayObject` cunstructur to clone an array like the following:

```
$myArray = array(1, 2, 3);
$clonedArray = new ArrayObject($myArray);
```

Comment: no need for new object explicitly, just call copy method on the original to get the clone. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.getarraycopy.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have *multidimensional array* or array composed of *both objects and other values* you can use this method:

```
$cloned = Arr::clone($array);
```

from [that library](https://github.com/minwork/array).

Answer (score 0):

Just include this function in all of your classes. This will do a deep clone of all objects in case if you have arrays of objects within the object itself. It will trigger all of the `__clone()` functions in these classes:

```
/**
 * Clone the object and its properties
 */
public function __clone()
{
    foreach ($this as $key => $property)
    {
        if(is_array($property))
        {
            foreach ($property as $i => $o)
            {
                if(is_object($o)) $this->$key[$i] = clone $o;
                else $this->$key[$i] = $o;
            }
        }
        else if(is_object($property)) $this->$key = clone $property;
        else $this->$key = $property;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
$a = ['a'=>'A','b'=>'B','c'=>'C'];
$b = $a+[];
$a['a'] = 'AA'; // modifying array $a
var_export($a);
var_export($b);
```

Result:

```py
array ( 'a' => 'AA', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C', )
array ( 'a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C', )
```

Comment: The elements in these arrays are scalar values, so are not object references. This does not answer the question.

Comment: This is an excellent solution if you have all scalar values in an array 
OR 
you want a shallow copy in case of objects.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer recursive way:

```php
function deepClone(mixed $object): mixed
{
    switch (gettype($object)) {
        case 'object':
            return clone $object;

        case 'array':
            $ret = [];
            foreach ($object as $key => $item) {
                $ret[$key] = deepClone($item);
            }
            return $ret;

        default:
            return $object;
    }
}

deepClone($array);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes