# Copy a PHP array item that contains an object

Tags: php, arrays, object, reference, copy

I would like to copy an array item that contains an object.

```
$arr = [
    'first_item' => [
        'label' => 'a',
        'date' => new DateTime('1999-12-30')
    ],
    'second_item' => [
        'label' => 'b',
        'date' => new DateTime('1999-12-31')
    ]
];

$copy = $arr['second_item'];
$copy['label'] = 'c'; // OK, does not affect $arr['second_item']
$copy['date']->setDate(2000, 1, 1); // changes $arr['second_item'] as well
```

Just out of ideas, I tried to replace `$copy = $arr['second_item']` by `$copy = clone $arr['second_item']` but it (understandably) fails with a *"Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object"* message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone an array of objects in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418903/how-to-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-php)

Comment: Try `$copy = (new ArrayObject($arr))->getArrayCopy();`

Comment: @MetodMedja: Tried, but I get the same result.