# How can I copy associative array items to another single array item recursively?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, associative-array

I have an associative array with keys that are numbered like software release version numbers, for example `32.1`, what I want to do is take each of the versions following `32.1` (32.2, 32.3, 32.4, etc) and assign them to another array under the `32` key, more so I need the script to be recursive, so that longer version numbers with multiple releases end up in the correct array keys.

My code...

```
<?php

    $array = array(
        '1' => 'Level 1',
        '1-1' => 'Level 1',
        '1-2' => 'Level 1',
        '1-2-1' => 'Sub-Level 1',
        '2' => 'Level 2',
        '3' => 'Level 3'
    );

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        static $assoc = array();

        if (preg_match('/-/', $key)) {
            $points = explode('-', $key);
            $assoc_key = basename($key, '-' . end($points));
            $assoc[$assoc_key]['sub'][$key] = array('1' => 'Sub-' . $array[end($points)]);
        } else {
            $assoc[$key] = array('1' => $array[$key]);
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>' . print_r($assoc, true) . '</pre>';

?>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Array
(
  [1] => Array
    (
      [1] => Level 1
      [sub] => Array
        (
          [1-1] => Array
            (
              [1] => Sub-Level 1
            )

          [1-2] => Array
            (
              [1] => Sub-Level 2
              [sub] => Array
                (
                  [1-2-1] => Array
                    (
                      [1] => Sub-Sub-Level 1
                    )

                )

            )

        )

    )

  [2] => Array
    (
      [1] => Level 2
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
      [1] => Level 3
    )

)
```

**Actual Output**

```
Array
(
  [1] => Array
    (
      [1] => Level 1
      [sub] => Array
        (
          [1-1] => Array
            (
              [1] => Sub-Level 1
            )

          [1-2] => Array
            (
              [1] => Sub-Level 2
            )

        )

    )

  [1-2] => Array
    (
      [sub] => Array
        (
          [1-2-1] => Array
            (
              [1] => Sub-Level 1
            )

        )

    )

  [2] => Array
    (
      [1] => Level 2
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
      [1] => Level 3
    )

)
```

Can anyone help?

I just know it's something simple I'm missing, but I've been trying to get this to work for two days now.

Comment: Maybe a [dup of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418903/how-to-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-php#6418936)?

Comment: Are you sure your input array is correct? 1-1 and 1-2 shouldn't be Sub-Level 1 and 1-2-1 Sub-Sub Level 1?

Comment: halfer: No it isn't. This ask is able adding items with similar keys in one array into another array under singular keys, as to "group" them.

Comment: mTorres: That part's not really important, nonetheless, the "level" number in each "sub" item should start from "1" again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with something that could solve your problem using array references.

Probably the code can be further optimized as well, but should be enough to show the concept.

As you stated, the function has to be recursive, but you used an iterative approach.

```
<?php
  $array = array(
    '1' => 'Level 1',
    '1-1' => 'Level 1',
    '1-2' => 'Level 1.2',
    '1-2-1' => 'Level 1.2.1',
    '2' => 'Level 2',
    '3' => 'Level 3'
  );

  $assoc = array();

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, "-") !== false) {
      $points  = explode('-', $key);
      $current = &$assoc[$points[0]];
      $str     = $points[0];
      for ($i = 1; $i < count($points); $i++) {
        $str    .= "-" . $points[$i];
        if (!isset($current["sub"]))
          $current["sub"] = array();
        $current = &$current["sub"][$str];
      }
      $current[1] = 'Sub-' . $value;
    }
    else {
      $assoc[$key][1] = $array[$key];
    }
  }


  echo '<pre>' . print_r($assoc, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: After much testing, I've found this to be a perfect solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**you are getting this kind of result because when you are constructing the `$assoc_key` if you got $assoc_key='1-2' you should not construct `$assoc[$assoc_key]['sub'][$key] = array('1' => 'Sub-' . $array[end($points)]);` because it will create a new array with base id '1-2' you should create `$assoc[$pre_asscokey]['sub'][$assoc_key][$key] = array('1' => 'Sub-' . $array[end($points)]);`
 so try this:

```
   <?php

    $array = array(
        '1' => 'Level 1',
        '1-1' => 'Level 1',
        '1-2' => 'Level 1',
        '1-2-1' => 'Sub-Level 1',
        '2' => 'Level 2',
        '3' => 'Level 3'
    );
    static $assoc = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {


        if (preg_match('/-/', $key)) {
            $points = explode('-', $key);
            $assoc_key = basename($key, '-' . end($points)); 
            $x=$points[0];
            if($assoc_key == $pre_asscokey  && sizeof($points)==3){
          $assoc[$x]['sub'][$pre_asscokey]['sub'][$key] = array('1' => 'Sub-' . $array[end($points)]);
            }else{
            $assoc[$assoc_key]['sub'][$key] = array('1' => 'Sub-' . $array[end($points)]);
         $pre_asscokey = $key;
            }
        } else {
            $assoc[$key] = array('1' => $array[$key]);
            $pre_asscokey=$key;
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>' . print_r($assoc, true) . '</pre>';

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Level 1
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [1-1] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Sub-Level 1
                        )

                    [1-2] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Sub-Level 2
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                    [1-2-1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [1] => Sub-Level 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Level 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => Level 3
        )

)
```

Comment: I've tried this approach before, it too is wrong because `$array['1-2-1']` ends up in `$assoc['1']['sub']` when it should end up in `$assoc['1']['sub']['1']['1-2']` and so on.

Comment: suchit: I've tested it now, and it isn't recursive, it only works with two levels at most. Which is what I'm finding so difficult to solve.