# PHP pointers vs references

Tags: php, pointers, reference

In PHP, what is the difference between using a pointer such as:

```
function foo( $var )
{
    $var = 3;
}

$a = 0;
foo( &$a );
```

And reference:

```
function foo( &$var )
{
    $var = 3;
}

$a = 0;
foo( $a );
```

They both modify the value of the original variable, but are they represented differently internally?

Comment: use the second one since the first is no longer supported / available.

Comment: Yes, they works the same way, this is message from PHP 5.3.8 for the 1st alternative: `Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated; If you would like to pass it by reference, modify the declaration of foo(). If you would like to enable call-time pass-by-reference, you can set allow_call_time_pass_reference to true in your INI file in C:\xampp\htdocs\a.php on line 8`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In PHP, there are no pointers, only references. Your examples demonstrate [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

The difference between your code snippets is only in syntax, where the first syntax is now deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware they were the same thing or that the first style was deprecated. Also, doesn't passing by reference store a reference to the passed variable in the function argument? If so, how are no references involved?

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure how pass-by-reference is implemented internally. I only think about it differently because many languages have pass-by-reference, but no references as PHP has. But that has nothing to do with your question, so I removed the confosing part.

Comment: Is passing by reference a better practice in terms of memory management?

Comment: @JomarSevillejo No, as PHP employs [copy-on-write semantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074970/will-copy-on-write-prevent-data-duplication-on-arrays), there shouldn't really be a noticable performance difference.