# Does php's copy on write work with arrays?

Tags: php, copy-on-write

Does php's copy on write work with arrays? Also if you could suggest a way to debug when a copy on write is happening that would be appreciated

Comment: You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will copy-on-write prevent data duplication on arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074970/will-copy-on-write-prevent-data-duplication-on-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

> Does php's copy on write work with arrays?

Yes it does.

> [Will copy-on-write prevent data duplication on arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074970/will-copy-on-write-prevent-data-duplication-on-arrays#:%7E:text=Copy%20on%20write%20as%20the,references%20thanks%20to%20this%20mechanism.)

Yes, as long as no single byte is changed.

Comment: If this is a duplicate of the other answer, please flag it as such. Don't post answes that only refer to another question

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) This question is still worth answering (which I did in one line), the remaining is just additional resources (even if that link may answer the question indirectly).

Comment: If you think that this is a distinct question, please add more details to your answer