# How copy value of Php array variable to another array

Tags: php, arrays

Friends . Read full details to understand problem.

```
 av = array("$a1","$a2","$a3"); //  used here loop for that to create auto varibles

 av[i] = $_POST("***"); // something code ...which assign values to array   using loop

 echo " $a1 $a2  " // its display correct value
```

now my problem is

i want to copy all array variables **av** values to **var** array vaiables.

var array consist variables like " $a1 " many times.

```
             var = array("$a1","$a1","$a1","$a2","$a2","$a3");
```

**var** array consist defined  order . i want values in that sequence.

i want output

```
           echo  "var[0] var[1] var[2] " ;// it display value of $a1
```

or how create another array which copy values of array vaiables  **av** . and sequence equal to array **var**

Update 1 :

update 1 :

AV array consist variables suppose 4. a = array ( "$a1" , "$a2" , "$a3", "$a4"  ) . // actually i used loop for that its near 20 - 30 variables.

Now I  assigned values to $a1 , $a2 , ... using for loop and POST method.

if i write

```
         echo  " a[0] " ;  // it display $a1

         echo " a1 = $a1"; // it display  actual value that i need eg. a1= 555

       $v = array ( "$a1" , "$a1" ,"$a1" , "$a1");

       now  i want To print array $v with value. 

      now $v[0] consist value $a1. 
      if i print $v[0] it display $a1. but i need value of $a1 i.e 555

       OR same $v array with actual variables values with same order
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532618/is-there-a-function-to-make-a-copy-of-a-php-array-to-another?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt rly understand what your actual problem is, but it seems like you want to merge 2 arrays together. Then you should take a look at `array_merge()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$av = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$var = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
$output =  array_merge($av, $var);
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => a
    [6] => b
    [7] => c
    [8] => d
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did I read this right?

Don't forget your `$` and your semicolons at the end.

```
   $av = array("Cow", "Chicken", "Hen", "Rooster");
    $var = array();
    foreach($av as $k=>$v){
    $var[$k] = $v;
    }
    echo  "$var[0] $var[1] $var[2] ";
```

Comment: `$var = $av` - what are you looping for?

Comment: The OP obviously doesn't know the solution, else he wouldn't be asking. Your code can simply be replaced with one `=`, and should be. Looping is absolutely pointless here.

Comment: very true, but he asked a question and i answered it the way he requested. what's the problem?

Comment: Not Work .. Read  Update 1 . array $var consist sequence variable $a1, $a1, $a1, $a2 .   now how assing values to it which have already value like $a=555