# Implode an array without first element

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have an array like this:

```
[0]=>array( [cname] => ABC
            [12] => 60.7500
            [13] => 33.7500
            [14] => 47.7500
            [15] => 86.0000
            [16] => 62.2500
            [17] => 59.5000
            [18] => 78.0000
            [19] => 42.7500
            [20] => 36.0000
            [21] => 40.0000
            [22] => 40.0000
            [23] => 24.0000
    )
)
```

Now, I have to print the `cname` in one field and in next field I have to print its data using `implode` function. It works fine. But When I implode it, it also gives the company name as well, which I do not want.

Desired Result:

```
Name: ABC
Data: 60.7500, 33.7500, 47.7500 ....
```

How can I skip the first element using implode?

Comment: Why do you have an array like that in the first place? Why not a multidimensional `array('name' => 'ABC', data => array(...))`?

Comment: Because I have to display data in the highcharts therefore, it is necessary to have the array format like that.

Comment: what is cname? looks like constant.

Comment: `implode(', ', array_slice($array, 1))` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just copy the array, then delete the `cname` property before calling `implode`.

```
$copy = $arr;
unset($copy['cname']);
implode($copy);
```

This works because in PHP, [array assignment copies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533214/465378). (Sort of bizarre, but it works.)

Comment: I know this is old but came up to it right know and was wondering which solution is more efficient or clean, yours or what @Darren suggests in the comments above (comments of question): `implode(', ', array_slice($array, 1))`?

Answer (score 6):

Use `array_shift` followed by `implode`.

```
$array = YOUR_ORIGINAL_ARRAY;

$cname = array_shift($array);
$string = implode(',', $array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$removedElementValue = array_shift($yourArray);
$implodedArray = implode(',', $yourArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since not all viewers are reading the comments, here the best answer for me from [@darren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164039/implode-an-array-without-first-element#comment44698965_28164039):

```
implode(', ', array_slice($array, 1))
```